# ¿Como ocultar un botón mediante un dato JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Hola comunidad espero me puedan apoyar, estoy tratando de ocultar o deshabilitar un botón mediante la información que obtengo mediante un JSON. A mi botón le coloque un id llamado `CrearCandidato`

Este es mi script para obtener mi objeto JSON

```
    <script>
    const crearCandidatoBoton = document.querySelector("#CrearCandidato");
    fetch("/Vacantes/ListaVacantes")
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.comentariosAuto === null) {
                crearCandidatoBoton.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
</script>
```

Este es el objeto que obtengo:

```
{
"idVacante": 0,
"fechaInicio": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"idPlaza": 0,
"idEntrevistador": 0,
"idDepartamento": 0,
"idPuesto": 0,
"idEstatus": 0,
"descripcion": null,
"comentariosSol": null,
"comentariosAuto": null,
"comentariosCH": null
```

}

Lo que quiero es ocultar el botón para los elementos que tengan `comentariosAuto:null` pero no logró ocultarlo, me podrian apoyar en comentarme en que estoy haciendo mal ?

Answer (score 2):

Sólo te hace falta convertir el objeto `JSON` a un objeto `javascript`:

```
const crearCandidatoBoton = document.querySelector("#CrearCandidato");

fetch("/Vacantes/ListaVacantes")
  .then(res => {
      return res.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
      let objeto = JSON.parse(data);
      
      if (objeto.comentariosAuto === null) {
          crearCandidatoBoton.style.display = 'none';
      }
  });
```

Comment: Hola caprilo, a la hora de convertirlo me sale un error "Espero un token o un Obj" y que no es valido el JSON.parse

Comment: Entonces es posible que lo que tienes sea ya un objeto javascript, y no un JSON. ¿Qué sale en la consola si escribes `console.log(typeof(data))` dentro del bloque `then`, @Hectorepg?